# How to derive odd double factorial from falling factorial

Tags: taylor-expansion

I'm writing a C function to generate a series expansion for the Maclaurin series for the inverse cosine function, to test a math library. I'm using the series expansion to build a lookup table so that I can test each math function independently of other functions in the library.

Now, on the inverse cosine [page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseCosine.html) on Wolfram MathWorld, they show the numerator of the Maclaurin series for inverse cosine with $x$ in the interval $[-1, +1]$ as $$\left({1\over2}\right)_{n-1}$$
After a few hours of searching, I finally backed over the fact that this is the notation for a falling factorial. I had already worked out empirically that the computational equivalent of the numerator has to be $$(2n-1)!!\over {2^{n-1}}$$
I found some information on fractional factorials that involve the gamma function, but the Maclaurin series for inverse cosine with $x$ in the interval (-$\infty, +\infty)$ has the gamma function in the numerator and $\sqrt\pi$ in the denominator; these have already been reduced and factored out for the shortened interval.

My problem is that I need to show how the computational implementation of the series expansion derives from the published version of the series for the documentation of the test, and I cannot for the life of me get from the fractional falling factorial to the fraction with the odd double factorial. Bonus hoorahs and kudos if someone can tell me that this is by definition.

Comment: Hint: Expand the derivative 
$$\arccos'(x)=\frac{-1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=-(1-y)^{-1/2}$$
with the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series and integrate termwise.

Comment: @gammatester: Thanks for the quick response. If I'm not mistaken (which, I'll grant you, is a very real possibility), won't integrating the expanded derivative give me the terms of the series?